# Remove explicit JavaScript backslash escaping

Tags: javascript, asp.net-web-api, escaping

I have been searching to solve what I expected to be not that obscure of a task, but I have not come across a working solution yet. Perhaps I am fundamentally wrong as to what I am experiencing, and why, but I would certainly like to borrow some eyes on it and insight into **why**.

**Task**

Print the literal string `console.log('\\u0027\\u0027\\u0027\\u0027');`

as `''''`

I instead get `'\u0027\u0027\u0027\u0027'`

I see this is caused by the explicit escaping, but how can I transform or remove the double backslashes to give me the desired result?

**Scope Details**

I am returning a collection from a .NET web api backend and encoding the collection using `System.Web.HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode` which is returning the explicit double backslash values in my JavaScript for any found special characters.

**Edit**

backend mock example

```
public ActionResult GetDictionary()
{
    var collection =
        this.service.Get()
            .OrderBy(x => x.Name)
            .Select(x =>
                    new Item()
                        {
                            Name = x.Name,
                            PreviewData = System.Web.HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(x.PreviewData),
                            Description = System.Web.HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(x.Description)
                        })
            .ToList();

    return this.Json(collection, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the relevant portions of your .NET backend?

Comment: What if you just remove one slash console.log('\u0027\u0027\u0027\u0027');

Comment: @RyanE, that would work, how?

Comment: @scniro did you want to replace \\ with single \? If not, i'll delete mine.

Comment: @cbuckley backend example posted

Comment: Either remove the `JavaScriptStringEncode()` call, or remove the escape sequences from the data that the service provides.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May look hack-ish, but if you want to keep it short then:

```
var myValue = '\\u0027\\u0027\\u0027\\u0027';
console.log( JSON.parse( '"' + myValue + '"' ) );
```

JSON.parse needs double quotes, that's the only unpretty part in it.

Comment: The OP wants to remove them on the serverside probably

Comment: That could be wiser of course, but maybe someone else will benefit from this in the future (same problem, but no access to serverside).

Comment: ahh, nice. The double quotes needed is what got me. Thanks @Ingmars